# Creating a dropdown menu with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble creating a simple dropdown menu nested inside the navigation bar. I have it so that when you hover over the navigation link dropdown appears, however, it disappears when you move down into the box- you can't. I want to be able to navigate in the dropdown box. I have been trying to do this with CSS and recently have tried with JS (though I am very new with JS so sorry, bear with me) I am having trouble understanding how to connect and apply a CSS class with JS so that it only works when you want it to.

```js
   const dropdown = document.querySelector('.second-nav-list-wrapper')

    dropdown.onmouseenter = () => {
    dropdown.classList.toggle('second-nav-list')
    }
```

```css
    .second-nav{
    position:relative;
    }

    .second-nav-list{
    visibility:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Raleway';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    background-color:rgb(235, 245, 252);
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display:flex;
    }

    .second-nav-link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(59, 53, 53);
    }

    .header-nav-link-dropdown:hover .second-nav .second-nav-list{
    visibility:visible;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:rgb(208, 215, 230);
    }
```

```html
<nav class="header-wrapper">
        <ul class= "header-nav">
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper header-nav-link-dropdown">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Recipes</a>
                    <nav class="second-nav">
                        <ul class="second-nav-list">
                            <div class= "second-nav-list-wrapper">
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Breakfast</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Lunch</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Snacks</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Dinner</a>
                            </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </li>
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Cookbooks</a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Your javascript is mixed with your css code

Comment: I did a snippet out of it

Comment: What is your goal i dont understand it

Comment: FYI: Your HTML is invalid. a `ul` element may only have `li` elements as direct children.

Comment: When you mouse over recipes a dropdown list will appear. But then when you try to move inside the dropdown menu it disappears before you can navigate it, Thank you for snippet, I don't know how to do those

Comment: As Scott Marcus stated, your HTML is invalid. Second, why do you need to use JS for a dropdown menu in the first place? It can be doen with the simple use of `:hover` alone.

Comment: how should I rewrite the HTML? I can't get the menu to stay open with the use of hover alone

Comment: So I should delete the second nav and second nav list wrapper and their elements?

Comment: Changing the HTML around worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it. We use the `onmouseover` to open the dropdown. We use the `onmouseleave` event to close it. Note we are using `onmouseleave` on the whole navbar so we only close the dropdown when the mouse leaves the navbar and all it's children.

Here are also some examples of how other mouse hover events behave:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_leave_out
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_over_enter

```js
      const dropdown = document.querySelector('.second-nav-list');
      const recipies = document.querySelector('.recipies');
      const navbar = document.querySelector('.header-nav')

      //this function toggles visibiltity on
      recipies.onmouseover = () => {
            dropdown.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
      //this one toggles it off
      navbar.onmouseleave = () => {
            dropdown.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
```

```css
            .second-nav{
    position:relative;
    }

/* added background color here, removed the on-hover */
    .second-nav-list{
    visibility:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Raleway';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    background-color:rgb(208, 215, 230);
    color:rgb(59, 53, 53);
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="header-wrapper">
        <ul class= "header-nav">
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper header-nav-link-dropdown">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link recipies">Recipes</a> <!-- Changed -->
                    <nav class="second-nav">
                        <ul class="second-nav-list">
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Breakfast</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Lunch</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Snacks</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=# class="second-nav-link">Dinner</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </li>
            <li class="header-nav-link-wrapper">
                <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Cookbooks</a>
            </li> 
  </ul>
  </nav>
```